# Unexpected pixels when loading a raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

After adding and zooming to my .jp2 raster, I am getting unexpected pixels (see screenshot).
It only happens when I zoom in.
Does anyone know if this is fixable or is it just a bad raster?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works